# MySQL workbench is deleted after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.4

Tags: ubuntu, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-18.04

i was working on Ubuntu 18 and i installed MySQL workbench form Ubuntu store , now i upgraded my Ubuntu to new version and no MySQL workbench found in my system ,I tried to download it again from Ubuntu store and i did't found it  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Workbench has not been updated yet to support Ubuntu 19.04. The upcoming version will, however.